# How to get the coordinates of bounding box for dets in dlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dlib

I am trying to get the coordinates of dets in order to write name above the detected face using dlib library.

```
import dlib

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()

dets = detector(img, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the below source code

```
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
dets = detector(img, 1)

for (i, det) in enumerate(dets):
    #you can draw name based on faceRect
    #to get top left point 
    top_left_point= det.tl_corner
    print (top_left_point.x, top_left_point.y)
```

Comment: i got this error in return: faceRect = det.rect

AttributeError: 'dlib.rectangle' object has no attribute 'rect'

Comment: so det is already a rectangle. edited my answer. You can refer more here http://dlib.net/python/index.html#dlib.rectangle

Comment: thanks for the help i discover that using imutils face utilities works for  me

Answer (score 0):

use imutils.face_utils rect_to_bb to declare the coordinates

```
for det in dets:
    (x, y, w, h) = rect_to_bb(det)
```